# Fuzzy matching with pyspark or python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I'm trying to do fuzzy matching using pyspark or python, where I have 2 lists.

**i. cities standard values list**

```
Clarksburg 
Fremont 
San Leandro 
Albuquerque 
Columbus 
San Jose 
Martinez 
New York
Alhambra
Unknown
Las Vegas
Dublin
Niagara Falls
```

**ii. wrongly spelled list of city names**

```
Clarksburg 
Closed 10/97
Fre,Nont
Fremong
San L:Eandro
Albuquerue
Clmbs
Sanjse
Martinz
New Yrk
Alambra
00011
L Vegas
Vegas
Ssan jose
Nw Yrk
Colmbus
Klarkburg
Alburque
Dublin
Niegara F
```

Now I want to match the wrongly spelled city names with the list of the standard values and created another list with appropriate matching. I'm looking for below output

```
Clarksburg - Clarksburg
Closed 10/97 - Unknown
Fre,Nont - Fremont
Fremong - Fremont
San L:Eandro - San Leandro
Albuquerue - Albuquerque
Clmbs -Columbus
Sanjse - San Jose
Martinz - Martinez
New Yrk - New York
Alambra - Alhambra
00011 - Unknown
L Vegas - Las Vegas
Vegas - Las Vegas
Ssan jose - San Jose
Nw Yrk - New York
Colmbus - Columbus
Klarkburg - Clarksburg
Alburque - Albuquerque
Dublin - Dublin
Niegara F - Niagara Falls
```

Any help would really help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fuzzywuzzy`, and change `threshold` to meet your requirements:

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import process

threshold = 40

matchlist = [x for x in """
Clarksburg
Fremont
San Leandro
Albuquerque
Columbus
San Jose
Martinez
New York
Alhambra
Unknown
Las Vegas
Dublin
Niagara Falls
""".splitlines() if x]

checklist = [x for x in """
Clarksburg
Closed 10/97
Fre,Nont
Fremong
San L:Eandro
Albuquerue
Clmbs
Sanjse
Martinz
New Yrk
Alambra
00011
L Vegas
Vegas
Ssan jose
Nw Yrk
Colmbus
Klarkburg
Alburque
Dublin
Niegara F
""".splitlines() if x]

for check in checklist:
    match = process.extractOne(check, matchlist)
    print(f"{check} - {match[0] if match[1] > threshold else 'Unknown'}")
```

This gives me:

```
Clarksburg - Clarksburg
Closed 10/97 - Unknown
Fre,Nont - Fremont
Fremong - Fremont
San L:Eandro - San Leandro
Albuquerue - Albuquerque
Clmbs - Columbus
Sanjse - San Jose
Martinz - Martinez
New Yrk - New York
Alambra - Alhambra
00011 - Unknown
L Vegas - Las Vegas
Vegas - Las Vegas
Ssan jose - San Jose
Nw Yrk - New York
Colmbus - Columbus
Klarkburg - Clarksburg
Alburque - Albuquerque
Dublin - Dublin
Niegara F - Niagara Falls
```

Comment: How to set threshold? and why did we set it to 40 in our case?

Comment: @DeepakSanagapalli  The value is between 0 and 100 based on the confidence of the match.  I set it to 40 because `Closed 10/97` matches `Columbus` with a 34 confidence :-)

Comment: Thanks @MikeOrganek, hope it will work for my requirement. Can you also help me in showing the match score beside each result?

Comment: @DeepakSanagapalli  Use this in lieu of the existing `print()`:  `print(f"{check} - {match[0] if match[1] > 0 else 'Unknown'} {match[1]}")`

Comment: Instead of list can we also use csv or txt files for matchlist and checklist? if so what would be the change?

Comment: @DeepakSanagapalli  You can populate the lists from files.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: Hi @Mike Organek, I have another question, i want to map the value as MULTICOLOR if there are multiple colors in the check list

example:
WHITE & Brown - MULTICOLOR
BROWN BLACK - MULTICOLOR
TAN/BLACK/RED - MULTICOLOR
SLVR& BLK - MULTICOLOR

Comment: @DeepakSanagapalli  I am sorry, but I do not think you are asking the right person.  This question was about fuzzy matching city names.